# Bootstrap 3 segmented dropdown & button spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a button group which is text input, dropdown then submit button.

I want them all to be joined [Like Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented) But am getting a gap after the dropdown and can't figure out why.

```
<form class="col-lg-10">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-btn">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
        hoose <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.input-group -->
</form>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/XL29h/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of elements inside that input group are `display: inline-block`.

Any space between inline elements will create "space".

If you remove space (and newlines) between `</button><ul>` and `</ul><button>` you will lose that gap.

This trick gives "unexpected gaps" in many situations and any CSS developer should write this behavior down, for future bug fixing.